# Fire baseでGoogleで登録後、パスワード入力させる

Tags: firebase

note.comのようにGoogleで登録後、アカウントを選択した後、そのアカウントのメールアドレスが反映された状態でパスワード入力画面にしたいです。

この時Googleアカウントのメールアドレスは変更でき、変更しなかった場合、そのGoogleアカウントでもログインできる且つメールアドレスとパスワードでもログインできる二重の登録のようになっています。

実際にFirebaseでGoogleで登録をし、アカウントを選択すると、その時点でFirebaseに登録されてしまいます。

そうではなく、note.comのように、Googleアカウント登録と、自社サーバにもパスワードで管理したいです。

どもyいうなFirebase autoの関数を使えば良いでしょうか。
複数を可能にするAuthLinkではありませんでした